# Не удается провести биндинг в стиле

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть такой стиль

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemSaveStyle">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#242f3d"/>
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#b0b0b0"/>
                
        <Style.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isNeedSave}" Value="true"> 
               <Setter Property="Header" Value="Save*"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#879daf" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#202b36"/>
        </Trigger>
                    
         <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#879daf" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#202b36"/>
         </Trigger>

   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Это свойство:

```cs
   public bool isNeedSave
        {
            get
            {
                if (NewElements.Count != OldElements.Count)
                    return true;

                for(int i = 0; i < NewElements.Count; i++)
                {
                    bool isNew = true;

                    for (int j = 0; j < OldElements.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (NewElements[i].ToLower().Equals(OldElements[j].ToLower()))
                        {
                            isNew = false;
                        }        
                     
                    }
                    if (isNew)
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

А вот где я задаю контекст для окна:

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LB_Elements.ItemsSource = NewElements;
            DataContext = this;

        }
```

Проблема в том, что DataTrigger не в какую не хочет работать.

Comment: А если значение по умолчанию прописать, до `<Style.Triggers>`, как цвета?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Работает, но только если убрать Header в самом объявлении MenuItem. Но тригер по прежнему не работает

Comment: У MenuItem DataContext другой. Вот вы выставили ItemsSource, теперь у каждого элемента MenuItem: DataContext выставляется равный соответствующем элементу NewElements. А свойство находится в общем DataContext, поэтому триггер и не реагирует никак, свойства этого нет у него в контексте. Тут нужно обратится к элементу выше по дереву, через тот же RelativeSource у  байдинга.

Comment: @John С помощью какого именно RelativeSource? Там много их, я не разбираюсь как, есть ближайший к родителю, но я так понимаю что это работает только с элементами управления по типо Window. А как привязать именно к классу MainWindow?

Comment: Вопрос решен. {Binding Path=isNeedSave,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}

Comment: RelativeSource работает с любым типом. Можно и конкретно MainWindow указать. На самом деле, если его и использовать, то лучше привязываться непосредственно к родительскому элементу, т.е. к ItemsControl. А вообще, лучше свойство isNeesSave перенести в VM соответствующего элемента и его менять.